# Python Print statement doesn't overwrite previous line with \r

Tags: python-2.7, printing

I am trying to overwrite a printed line in Python2.7

```
from __future__ import print_function
import time
print('This is the first statement', end='\r')
time.sleep(1)
print('This is the Second Statement')
```

From this I would expect the first printed line, then one second later, the second printed line, overwriting the first one.

What I get when I execute the code is just the second printed line one second after the script is run.  What is going on here?  How do I get the first statement to appear before the second then the overwrite?

Answer (score 2):

Use `sys.stdout.flush`:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import time
import sys
print('This is the first statement', end='\r')
sys.stdout.flush() 
time.sleep(1)
print('This is the Second Statement')
```

Comment: What is the theory behind the required flush?  Why is a flush() not required for other print actions?

Comment: the data is buffered calling flush will force your os to write it to the terminal. It is the time.sleep that is effecting it.